# Detecting the last center point of View before it's collision to another view using PanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipangesturerecognizer, 2d-games, xcode8.2

I'm having 2 Views and detecting their collision using following code. It's working fine if the object is moved slowly i.e it is giving the coordinates follows in the motion. However, when the View is thrown at a high velocity by gesture, the middle coordinated gets unnoticed.I'm only getting the initial and the end coordinates. When the 2 view gets collide, I want them to be as nearer to each other as possible.

```
func handlePan(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let view = pan.view
        switch pan.state
        {
        case .began, .changed, .possible, .ended:
            let point = pan.translation(in: view?.superview)
            print(point)
            let viewPoint = CGPoint(x: (view?.center.x)! + point.x, y: (view?.center.y)!+point.y)
            prevCenterB = viewBlue.center
            prevCenterR = viewRed.center
            view?.center = viewPoint
            if (viewRed.frame.intersects(viewBlue.frame))
            {
                print("Intersection")
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Collision of objects occured !!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
                let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(actionOK)
                alert.addAction(actionCancel)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                if view == viewRed
                {
                    view?.center = prevCenterR!
                }
                else
                {
                    view?.center = prevCenterB!
                }
            }
             pan.setTranslation(.zero, in: view?.superview)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth having a read of [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial) on UIKit Dynamics.

Comment: Thanks @Maarut. I've gone through Ray's tutorial but it is giving me a way to handle collisions b/w objects. But, I ant to know a way to figure out this using PANGesture. Further help will be appreciated !!